# Flutter - How to align Text and image widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've a `Card` that contains multiple `Text` with an `Image`. Now the image is in top-center I need to align that to the right side inside the card.

**I need all the text to the left side of the card and the image to the right side.**

So, basically All the `Text` should be on the left side and the `Image` should be on the right side.

*this is the card that I've implemented now,*

[image]

*Here is the code I've been implemented*

```
  Widget _buildItemsForListView(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(Constants.FOOD_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE_ASSET_URL, height: 50,width: 100),
          Text("Spinach soup",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple, fontSize: 16),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
          Text("SAR",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
              textAlign: TextAlign.left),
          Text("26",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
          Text(
            "Fresh spinach, mushrooms, and hard-boiled egg served with warm bacon vinaigrette",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
          Text("15.4" + " Calories",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

How to implement this?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: The question is very misdirecting.  I have suggested an edit, please accept it.

Comment: What more details you need? I have included all that I can provide in this question

Comment: Do you want the Image and Text side by side, or the Image at the top right corner and the Text at the bottom left corner?

Comment: @ João Soares!  I need all the text to the left side of the card and the image to the right side. I want the image side by side!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Card(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Spinach soup",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple, fontSize: 16),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    Text("SAR",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                    Text(
                      "26",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Fresh spinach, mushrooms, and hard-boiled egg served with warm bacon vinaigrette",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "15.4" + " Calories",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Image.network(
                    'https://3.img-dpreview.com/files/p/TS1200x900~sample_galleries/1330372094/1693761761.jpg',
                    height: 50,
                    width: 100),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: how to make padding for the elements? Now the left elements are close to the card, if I need to add some space there what should do?

Comment: Wrap column in a Padding widget !

Answer (score 1):

try providing the `crossAxisAlingment` parameter in the main `column` to align the text to left as following:

```dart
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

if you do this then including the Center image everything will be aligned to left.

so you have to wrap the current `column` in a `row` and move the image to the first one. Make sure that the image is added after the `column` widget to align it to right side.

it will look something like this:

```dart
return Card(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Spinach soup",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple, fontSize: 16),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
              Text("SAR",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left),
              Text("26",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
              Text(
                "Fresh spinach, mushrooms, and hard-boiled egg served with warm bacon vinaigrette",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
              Text("15.4" + " Calories",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,)
            ],
          ),
           Image.asset(Constants.FOOD_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE_ASSET_URL, height: 50,width: 100),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

NOTE: you can remove `crossAxisAlingment` from `Row`. I have added it just make it look good.

let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: I did as you said but there is an issue `A RenderFlex overflowed by 270 pixels on the right.` the image is not visible because it is out of the screen size

Comment: Add this to row:
`mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,`

Comment: this did nothing.. still the image is out of screen